# Object is used to send a message or receive a message?

Tags: objective-c, object

I am using **Objective-C**, I have a doubt in message passing terminology. In this line of code

```
[obj dosomething];
```

Whether Object `obj` is sending a message `dosomething`, or receiving a message?
If it sending a message then I want to know, what it exactly means? What could be happened in heap memory?

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-SW1

Comment: "Message sending" in Objective-C is purely a terminology quirk borrowed from early O-O languages.  `[obj dosomething]` is, according to this terminology, "sending" the message `dosomething` to the object `obj`.  In actual fact, this is a (relatively) simple call to the method `dosomething` of the object `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you the programmer are sending a message, `doSomething`, to the `obj` instance. Under the hood, this calls the Objective-C runtime method `objc_msgSend` on the `obj` instance. If `obj` implements `doSomething`, the method will be called, but if it does not, you'll get a "selector not recognized" exception, and your app will crash.